# Access Websphere MQ queue meta using JMS resources

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I want access some Websphere MQ queue meta information, such as current queue depth, maximum queue depth, etc. from EE application. I can deal with it using [com.ibm.mq.MQQueue](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueue.html) which I can obtain from [com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html#accessQueue_java.lang.String_int_). For obtaining `MQQueueManager` instance I need some information I've already specified for `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and `javax.jms.Queue` at application server (queue name, SSL configuration, etc.)

How I can access MQ queue meta information using JNDI name of `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and `javax.jms.Queue`?

I use WAS 8.5.5 and WMQ 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Accessing MQ via JMS will not get you the information you seek.  You should use the MQ PCF classes for Java.

Also, never process MQ messages based on queue depth.  You need to read the queue until it is empty.

Comment: I know that I can't receive that information using JMS. But I hope I can access meta information of connection factory (host, etc.) using WAS api. Or may be WAS provides receiveing of `com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager` from ConnectionFactory (by casting it to some WAS class).

Also I want use queue depth just for logging.